# Creating a dynamic ORM resource in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm looking to create a dynamic resource in tastypie.  Basically the idea is that there are a lot of models to hook up, so this may help save time with the standard no-frills resources.

I have most of this working, however I'm having trouble with the related fields being populated.  I'm overriding the constructor for a class that inherits from ModelResource, and in this constructor I'm attempting to set the tastypie relationships.  However when I review my resource the data is not being populated.

```
setattr(self, field, fields.ForeignKey(class_thing, attribute=field, full=True))
```

Basically I'm using setattr in the constructor to try and hook up what the relationship should be.  If I'm goofing off with the instance I can see this object is getting created but the resource output is not changing.  Is anyone familiar enough with tastypie/doing something like this to give me a clue?

Thanks for your time.

Edit: Nevermind, just overrode dehydrate and did this from there.

Comment: You should add what you did as an answer and accept it so the question is closed.

Comment: Yeah new member just was waiting for the timer to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than go through the constructor (which is messy since tastypie/django does stuff there anyway) I did this through a dehydrate override which is kind of designed to do this.

The bundle.obj has all the associated data there, so basically I just serialized the related objects and add them to the bundle.data dictionary before returning the bundle. Seemed cleaner and worked like a charm.